# How to run python module command from VSCode tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to run my alembic migration which is in a subdirectory so I am writing VSCode tasks for it but when I run it I get `command not found` error:

```json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Alembic autogenerated revision",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "alembic revision --autogenerate -m init",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/my_sub_directory"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I run it under my virtual environment?

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Kindly let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hi @MollyWang-MSFT Yes I got your answer but I don't want to hard code the path of python. Right now I am getting path from my config like `"command": "${config:python.defaultInterpreterPath} -m alembic revision --autogenerate -m ${input:alembic_revision_msg}",` but when I change the PC from work to home I have to update the `settings.json` file again. So I didn't found the perfect answer yet.

Comment: There's a feature in vscode called [setting sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync), please check if it helps you.

Comment: I do use settings sync but the problem is `python.defaultInterpreterPath` is different in both machines. Work home has `/home/work/pythonPath` and home has `/home/myName/pythonPython` so when I switch from work to home python path gets wrong due to settings sync.

Answer (score 0):

Activating the virtual environment, then installing `alembic`, you can run `alembic revision` directly, that's because it's in the virtual environment and able to call the module.

So, when executing `alembic` command in task, you also need to **activate env** first.

[image]

Copy the activation command and paste it before alembic and separated by `;` , the task should be ran successfully:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I've not been able to find a solution that doesn't require hardcoding the virtualenv path.

I believe an extension would be able to solve this, possibly by adding support for `python` in the tasks's `type` field.

### A workaround

**Use launch configurations instead of tasks for running python scripts.** It is a bit weird, but it works.

Here's your code adapted to `launch.json` schema:

```py
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Alembic autogenerated revision",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "alembic",
            "args": ["revision", "--autogenerate", "-m", "init"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/my_sub_directory"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, consider using [input variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) for specifying revision messages and other variable things.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. To resolve this we can use the selected interpreter path and run the module.

```json
        {
            "label": "Alembic autogenerated revision",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${command:python.interpreterPath} -m alembic revision --autogenerate -m init",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/ts_tools"
            }
        },
```

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18728

Regards.